# Site loading issue: Angular 6 project taking too much time to load

Tags: javascript, css, angular, performance, sass

[image: late loading performance graph]

In the above picture its clear that My application is taking too much time(3 mins as shown in the image) to load for the first time. I am not able to find the actual reason.

Some details about my application:

1. There are total only 13 components in my project.
2. I have not used lazy loading, because its not big enough in my point of view to use lazy loading. Because after build the main.js file size is just 2.4 MB
3. To minify the size i have even deleted the spec.ts files and unwanted .scss files.
4. There are 6 .svg files in the whole project.
5. This is the command I am using for building. ' ng-build --prod --aot '

If any further details is needed I ll provide , Please help me out in finding the actual reason behind the delay.

Comment: 2.4 MB not big for a production build??? What is big then? `spec.ts` files are not participating the bundle size at all

Comment: Have you tried eliminating https and see if the issue continues over standard http? beyond that, I suggest running speed test on your internet connection, if this is an intranet solution then start running speedtest on file transfers over the internal network.

Comment: Based on the timeline screenshot, it looks like the time is spent on the network fetching your code - if I remember Chrome's color coding correctly, the time is spent in download the response specifically. You should double check your network configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Take the advantage of angular router and module lazy loading. For example create module of relevant component and when the vie is visited load the specific js file

In the example when `customer` route is visited it will load the relevant js file so is other module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  }
];
```

Also you can run `ng build --prod`. This will compress the code, will eliminate dead code

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I ll try to convert my code using lazy loading..that may solve the issue

Comment: Does lazy loading is the only solution? Is there any other way to solve this.. because at this point converting my whole code will create a bit mess. So just asking

Answer (score 2):

1. It can be 13 components with 6K lines of code. Number of components don't matter, code complexity does.
2. Lazy loading doesn't reduce the bundle size : lazy loading is the features that loads the Javascript **when asked** instead of *when received*
3. `spec` files don't appear in the build, and `.scss` files are compiled into JS (making no difference in the final build, whether you use inline styling or URL styling)
4. See point n° 1
5. Again, similar to point n° 1, it depends on the commands you run and the code you need to compile.

I can't see images, but have you ran a [lighthouse audit](https://www.google.fr/search?q=lighthous+audit&rlz=1C1GCEU_frFR819FR820&oq=lighthous+audit&aqs=chrome..69i57.2031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on your application ? It might tell you what you can improve.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.Is there any other way to solve this other then lazy loading. because at this point converting my whole code will create a bit mess..

Comment: Lazy loading doesn't change your code (except for routing) and you can implement it in seconds. If your goal is to reduce the bundle size, I suggest you remove unused modules from your modules, remove unused dependencies, activate tree shaking, reduce your code complexity, implement server side rendering, lazy loading, and finally, depending on your server, you can load files according to the URL of your app.